# Changing configuration values in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, admob

I am seeking guidance on how to achieve the following:

- When I am running on Simulator, and optionally also on TestFlight (after I actually push the app to TestFlight and have my users install the latest) a variable is configured with value A
- When I then promote that build to production (approved in app store and ready for me to publish), the value then changes to a production value

The rationale for this is I am using Google AdMob and I'd like to use my test ad id whenever I run the simulator (and ideally whenever someone is on test flight, although maybe that's not a hard requirement). But when I am in prod, I'd like to use the prod value since Google will penalize you if you're running ads locally.

Is this idea, in a basic sense, achieved via a Schema? I'm a bit new to this (as well as targets) so wanted to see if that was possible.

Thank you!

Comment: easiest and fastest way to control test id's is using firebase remote config - https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-ios

Comment: if you are looking for firebase remote config solution, i can update answer with example on how we use it to config test ids

Comment: @AmodGokhale but this isn't environment specific is it? Meaning the same code would run to fetch the value regardless of whether I run locally or deploy?

Comment: that is correct. it is not environment specific... value will be retrieved every time.